# Is it possible to insert javascript into Google Chrome's "Inspect Element"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I click "Inspect Element" on a page in Google Chrome, is there a way for me to insert something like this (by clicking Edit HTML) to add a mouseover effect to the "a#link" element on the page?

```
$("a#link").mouseover(function() {
    $('div.linkcontents').slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: You can run the javascript in the console below the document tree pane. If the console is hidden you can click the second button from the left on the lower left corner to display it

Comment: Just run the script in the Console.

Comment: **@Esailija** or just press ESC.

Comment: Thanks Esailija! Worked great!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need the developer tools, how about just typing it in the browser address bar? Like this:

```
javascript:$("a#link").mouseover(function(){$('div.linkcontents').slideDown("slow");});
```

Comment: @supercoolville if it worked then you should accept the answer to show your appreciation

Answer (score -1):

Chrome is not an editor so you can't just insert HTML code. However since javascript is a scripting language you can go to the javascript console under tools in Chrome where you can run javascript code although it will not save it in the website.

Comment: Actually, you can, and you can even modify the running JavaScript files, even if they won't be saved if you reload the page. Pretty handy for quick tests, imho ;)

Comment: actually, you can even "just insert HTML code", but the question is not about it, yeah :)

Comment: since you now know that you can add content please update your answer to avoid confusion for other readers